Can I get the "EV Federal Income Tax Credit" if I moved to US in 2024 and want to use my previous 2023 year's income?
I moved to the US a few months ago at the start of 2024 and I am considering buying an EV. I am looking up all the rules for the EV tax credit and my this year's projected income will likely cross the threshold for the tax credit so I am ineligible using the current 2024 income.
However, the IRS rule also states that I can use my previous year's income to get the tax credit if it is below the threshold. Since I was not in the US in 2023, my income is $0 and I did not even file a tax return for it, my first tax return is going to be next year in April 2025.
Can I claim the tax credit using my previous year's $0 income or am I ineligible?
